# Registering remote procedures with autobahn java

Tags: java, hashmap, autobahn, method-reference, crossbar

The standard way of registering procedures in autobahn-java is:

```
CompletableFuture<Registration> order_to_produce = session.register(prefix + "order_to_produce", this::order_to_produce);
order_to_produce.thenAccept(registration -> LOGGER.info("Registered procedure: " + registration.procedure));
```

Since we have a lot of functions to register I was thinking to put registration names and functions to a HashMap but I am unable to reference any function with method reference.

I would like to make something like this:

```
    Map<String, Runnable> functions = new HashMap<>();
    functions.put("order_to_produce", this::order_to_produce);


    for (Map.Entry<String, Runnable> function : functions.entrySet())
    {
        CompletableFuture<Registration> registerProcedure = session.register(prefix + function.getKey(), function.getValue());
        registerProcedure.thenAccept(registration -> LOGGER.info("Registered procedure: " + registration.procedure));

        // or using reflection ?
        // 
        CompletableFuture<Registration> registerProcedure = session.register(prefix + function.getKey(), obj.getClass().getMethod(function.getKey()));
        registerProcedure.thenAccept(registration -> LOGGER.info("Registered procedure: " + registration.procedure));
    }
```

Is there a way to do this ?

In python I could do that with ease on backend component.

```
functions = {'backend.add_service': self.add_service,
             'backend.online_services': self.services_online}

for functionToRegister in functions.keys():
    yield self.register(functions[functionToRegister], functionToRegister, options=self.REGISTER_OPTIONS)
```

Regards, Marko.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still interested in original question but for now I made it so:

```
LinkedList<CompletableFuture<Registration>> functions = new LinkedList<>();
functions.add(session.register(prefix + "order_to_produce", this::order_to_produce));

for (CompletableFuture<Registration> function : functions) {
    function.thenAccept(registration -> LOGGER.info("Registered procedure: " + registration.procedure));
}
```